# Insert multiples time depending on variable php

Tags: php, mysql, variables, insert

Does anybody has an idea how to multiple insert depending on a variable?

```
$diff = abs(strtotime($datumtot) - strtotime($datumvan));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24) / (60*60*24));
```

Here i get the result back it can be 1 to 14.

now i want to insert it into the database.

My insert statement is a follows lets say days == 3

```
INSERT INTO example 
        (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES  (100,'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
        (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
        (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
```

is there a better way to do it? to check on the variable and then insert it how much it is?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried a FOR Loop?

Comment: I will try it thanks

Comment: Fixed it thanks buddy